# ASP.NET Session lost in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, fetch

I post this question cause i've passed lot of time to find the solution and find nothing about this on SO.

I'm using a `.NET` `WebAPI` as back end and store the user informations in the session.

For any reasons the `session` is lost in **Chrome**.

I receive the Set Cookie with the session id on my first request but the session is not set in Chrome but is set in IE.

I've  try to change the web.config several time and change the configuration of the server but nothing changed.

I'm using `fetch` API for call my services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on the fetch and not on the server side.

The strange thing is that it's work on IE. Apparently IE don't have the same policy for the fetch API.

You have to make sure to add the property `credentials` to `include` or `same-origin` to keep the session on your request.

**Warning** : Put credentials to `include` fire a security error in Chrome.
The `same-origin` value resolved my problem.

Example of request :

```
fetch(uri,{
   method:'GET',
   credentials:'same-origin'
})
.then()
.catch()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) does not send cookies by default. If your cookies are not [HTTP only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly), you have to set them manually in the headers collection.

Comment: Yeah, but i post this for help developers to identify the right problem (due to the fetch config and not from the server)